# I'm having problems on spliting a string number into single digits with Processing

Tags: processing

I'm new with processing and I'm trying to split any string digit into a single array element. Then my goal is to find home many numbers repeat themself anf print them out in an array. I'm not sure if I'm in the right track tho! I'm aware that there are some missing lines, but as I mention before I'm new and exploring the array, modulo and string area.

```java
   int[] dig = new string [1233467890]; 
   int n=dig.length;    

   while(n<0){
     arr[i--]=n%10
     dig = n % 10;
     n = n / 10;   
   }   
   println(arr);
```

Thanks ahead of time for help

Edwin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are mixing things up a little bit here, specially what strings and arrays are.

An array is a sequence of objects, and these objects may be integers, characters, booleans, circles, cups or balls. A String is, in the programming universe, a very special type of array: it is an array of characters.

So, as you may have noticed, there's no way of creating a "string" of integers. And the processing programming interface tells you exactly that if you try to run the code you posted:
"cannot convert [] String to [] Int". That means: strings and ints are things fundamentally different.

As I understood neither your goal nor your code, I can't help you any further.

I think it would be a better idea to read and understand the following link, run and understand the more basic examples there, and only then try to program what you want.

http://processing.org/reference/Array.html
http://processing.org/reference/String.html

Best regards

Comment: Thanks for your promp answer. I guess I have to understand some concepts first, if not all, before I continue. Thanks once again.